# How to set a variable to the result of a sql query with a variable as a table name in SQL 2005

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm currently having trouble writing a stored procedure and setting the value of a variable of type int to the results of a select statement with a variable as the tablename. I've looked at old threads and tried multiple methods, but no luck. If I'm not getting an error regarding the tablename, I end up getting an error with a variable conversion issue. I've been working on this for too long and any help would be appreciated. Below is a portion of my code. Thanks

```
DECLARE @BATCHNUMBER VARCHAR  --value set in earlier code
DECLARE @ETABLE VARCHAR(50); --the table name
DECLARE @FIRSTDOCID INT;      
SET @ETABLE = 'tablename_' + @BATCHNUMBER; --CREATE FIRST TABLE NAME

SELECT @FIRSTDOCID = MIN(D0CID) FROM @ETABLE
```

The error I get is: Must declare the table variable "@ETABLE"

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to select from a `VARCHAR`, not a table. The only way to make this work is by using Dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(250);
SET @SQL = 'SELECT @OUTPUT = MIN(D0CID) FROM ' + QuoteName(@ETABLE);
EXEC sp_executeSql @SQL, N'@output INT OUTPUT', @FIRSTDOCID OUTPUT;

SELECT @FIRSTDOCID;
```

However, I would not suggest using Dynamic SQL as this often leads to SQL injection.

Comment: this does not seem to work either because when I go and try and print the value of @firstdocid, I still dont get anything :/

Comment: I got a bit caught up in work, but I updated my code with a working example now.

Comment: I am supposed to enter it exactly as you have it, correct? Sorry I'm not too familiar with QuoteName or sp_executesql..when i do so, i receive the error: 
Invalid column name 'D0CID' 
But I assure you docid does exist in that table i have set to as @Etable becusae I run it as a seperate query and it works

Comment: hahah wait i just got it..you accidentally put a 0 instead of an O in @DOCID lol..nonethelessit works! THANK YOU! THIS IS THE ANSWER EVERYONE

Comment: Ah, I see the mistake. Copied the 0 from your post =). Could you accept the answer if this worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to do something like use `exec` if you're dynamically building the query:

```
SET @QUERY = "SELECT" + ...etc.
exec(@QUERY)
```

Since `ETABLE` is a varchar, and not, as expected, a 'table variable'.

Comment: tried this as well. It runs without any error but doesnt seem to actually set the value to @firstdocid because when I try to print it later, i get nothing